# AIME geometry question help

Tags: geometry

Square $ABCD$ has side length 144. Point $E$ is chosen on side $BC$ so that $AE + EB = 216$, and point $F$ is chosen on side $CD$ so that $\overline{AF}$ bisects $\angle DAE$. Find $DF$.

How would you solve this AIME qeustion. What would be the general steps needed ?

Comment: You can find the solution on AoPS or something

Comment: I tried but I could not find the test year or question number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by letting $BE=y$ and $AE=x$, so you have the system of equations

$$x+y=216\quad\text{and}\quad 144^2+y^2=x^2.$$

(The second equation comes from the Pythagorean Theorem.)

Solving this gives $x=156$ and $y=60$. Now, suppose $\angle BAE=\theta$ and $\angle EAD=\phi$. We know based on the values we just calculated that $\sin\theta=\frac{5}{13}$, and since $\theta+\phi=\frac{\pi}{2}$, we must also have $\cos\phi=\frac{5}{13}$. Now, since $AF$ bisects $\angle EAD$, we have $\angle FAD=\frac{\phi}{2}$, and so

$$\tan\frac{\phi}{2}=\frac{FD}{DA}\implies FD=144\tan\frac{\phi}{2}.$$

Since $\cos\phi=\frac{5}{13}$, we know that

$$\cos\frac{\phi}{2}=\sqrt{\frac{1+\frac{5}{13}}{2}}=\frac{3}{\sqrt{13}}.$$

Next,

$$\tan\frac{\phi}{2}=\sqrt{\sec^2\frac{\phi}{2}-1}=\sqrt{\frac{13}{9}-1}=\frac{2}{3},$$

so

$$FD=144\cdot \frac{2}{3}=96.$$